# Multiple Linear Regression Using Scikit-learn Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I'm relatively new to Python and I am trying to make a Multiple Linear Regression model which has two predictor variables and one dependent. While doing my research on this, I found that Scikit provides a class to do this. I tried to get a model for my variables and I got the following message:

```
Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (2, 1)
```

The code I've used is:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',delimiter=',',header=0)

SEED_VALUE = 12356789

np.random.seed(SEED_VALUE) 

data_train, data_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=SEED_VALUE)

print('Train size: {}'.format(data_train.shape[0]))
print('Test size: {}'.format(data_test.shape[0]))

data_train_X = data_train.values[:,0:2] #predictor variables
data_train_Y = data_train.values[:,2].astype('float') # dependant


model = linear_model.LinearRegression() 

np.random.seed(SEED_VALUE)

model.fit(data_train_X, data_train_Y)  


coef = pd.DataFrame([model.intercept_, *model.coef_], ['(Intercept)', *data_train_X.columns], columns=['Coefficients'])
coef
```

I got the Error in the `model.fit(data_train_X, data_train_Y)` line. I have searched online for different ways to use Scikit method and I have found that other people with the same code had no error, so I don't know where my mistake could be

Thank you all so much

The data file is like this:

```
"retardation","distrust","degree"
2.80,6.1,44
3.10,5.1,25
2.59,6.0,10
3.36,6.9,28
2.80,7.0,25
3.35,5.6,72
2.99,6.3,45
2.99,7.2,25
2.92,6.9,12
3.23,6.5,24
3.37,6.8,46
2.72,6.6, 8
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]. I think your title has room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you could also provide the input of the data, but even without it's most likely due to the fact that you use `index` column from your file. You should remove it and it will be fine.

If you can give the example of data that you use (columns), will be able to check it further.

I rerun your code, with the data you've provided and it does not show any errors for `model.fit(data_train_X, data_train_Y)` line :) [image]